# php curl request never finishing

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to call a API from curl, and this works fine in postman.when running in php this never goes passed the curl_exec call.have tried many options and read many other posts, but to no avail.Any advice appreciated

```
$url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?Season=2017-18&LeagueID=00&GameDate=10/17/2017&dayoffset=0";
//$url= urlencode($url);
$curl = curl_init($url);    // we init curl by passing the url
print("a");
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
#curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,false);   // to send a POST request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect: 100-continue'));
print("b");
#curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   // indicate the data to send
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
print("c");
#curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
print("d");
$result = curl_exec($curl) or die("cURL Error" . curl_error($curl));   // to perform the curl session
print("e");
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

From postman you can get the **generated code** also. This is what I got with your given URI, so lets try this and let me know whether it works or not?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?Season=2017-18&LeagueID=00&GameDate=10/17/2017&dayoffset=0",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: no still hangs, have a feeling its the nba stats web site somehow blovking it